# Looking for an MP3 player with playlist

Tags: music, music-player, mp3

I am looking for an MP3 player that has a playlist and that automatically loads MP3 files from a given folder.

I'm using Winamp, but it's not loading my files.

PS I've asked this question so I don't lose time searching and testing software

Comment: Software recommendations-type like questions are not welcome to this site or any in the SE network. And that is probably, why your question got -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [Meridian Player Transcend](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.iii.romulus.meridian&hl=en) and it's what I needed. I can play all the mp3 files from a folder (all songs in an album)